# awk timestamp set in begin block

Tags: awk, strftime

I'm setting a timestamp in a begin block:

```
BEGIN  { 
  timestamp = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
}
```

I don't update timestamp again in the rest of the script. I expect that timestamp won't change but it does.

Later in the script, I print `$0` to a file:

```
FNR>1{
  #do some stuff
  print $0 > "/mnt/data/logs/TEST_"timestamp".csv"
  ...
```

timestamp changes and it keeps printing to a new file. . . TEST_1.csv, TEST_2.csv . . .

It works as expected on a small file but when I use a full data file it prints multiple files

Comment: Something must be modifying `timestamp`. Can you show the rest of the code? What `awk` is this?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this using a file of 5 million lines.

Comment: BEGIN block is invoked only once, doesn't matter how many lines or files there are.  Perhaps you're calling the script more than once?

Comment: Search for the word "timestamp" in your file as it IS being modified in some section of code you haven't shown us. If you can't spot the problem then create the smallest script you can that exhibits this behavior and post that full script for us to see.

Comment: Yeah. I did that @EdMorton. I only set timestamp in the begin block.

Comment: awk -f validator.awk formatter.csv rawData/sample2.csv

@karakfa - I'm calling it like this where formatter contains templates that I'm using to parse/validate strings that are in the sample2.csv.

Comment: @EtanReisner - GNU Awk 4.0.1
I'll try and add the code.

Comment: For a quick test remove the BEGIN block and see what happens.

Comment: I moved 
`timestamp = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");`
to `FNR==1` block with the same results. I can't remove the entire begin block as I'm setting delimiters there.

Comment: I moved the timestamp setting to FNR==1 block with similar results.

`FNR==1 { 
$1=$1 
timestamp = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
#print header 
print $0 > "/mnt/data/work/sl_output.csv" print $0 > "/mnt/data/logs/sl_fail_output_"timestamp".csv" 
next 
}` 

I use timestamp here and here: 

`FNR>1 { 
print $0 > "/mnt/data/logs/sl_no_license_match_"timestamp".csv"` 
}`

Comment: Don't try to post formatted text, code or otherwise, in comments as it's unreadable - edit your question. I do see though that in your comment you appear to be setting timestamp in the FNR==1 block, NOT in the BEGIN block as you show in your question. That obviously WILL make a huge difference. Stop shuffling code around hoping magic will happen - just do what I asked and edit your question to show the smallest complete script you can create that produces the problem. Chances are by doing that exercise you'll figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I figured out the issue. I am calling an auxiliary awk script that I didn't think was relevant. Sorry for not including that originally. So when I call a logger function on that script it updates the timestamp variable. I fixed the issue by simply changing timestamp to timestamp1 on my script.

Thanks to all that responded and put up with my awk inexperience!